# define: cannot convert org.w3c.dom.domElement to boolean

Tags: java, javascript

I have translated the following Javascript code to Java. The problem occurs at sib;
http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/3754

I have never seen such for statements. What does it do exactly when you add a semicolon? Is this like while() statement?

```
 public static String getElementXpath(DOMElement elt){
        String path = ""; 
        for (;elt.ELEMENT_NODE == elt.getNodeType(); elt = (DOMElement) elt.getParentNode()){
            int idx = getElementIdx(elt);
        }
        return path;        
    }

    private static int getElementIdx(DOMElement elt) {
        int count = 1;

         for (DOMElement sib = (DOMElement) elt.getPreviousSibling(); sib ; sib = (DOMElement) sib.getPreviousSibling())
            {
                if(sib.ELEMENT_NODE == sib.getNodeType() && sib.getTagName() == elt.getTagName()) count++;
            }

        return count;
    }
```

Comment: Is this a question about the DOM, or a question about how Java for-loops work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you meant the first `for` loop:

```
for (;elt.ELEMENT_NODE == elt.getNodeType(); elt = (DOMElement) elt.getParentNode())
```

then the initial `;` indicates that there is no initialisation to be done.

A normal `for` loop is: **for (*initialise*; *expression*; *update*)** so your one only has the *expression* and *update* parts. There is no need for initialisation in your case because the `DOMElement` is passed in as a parameter and doesn't require any other steps before you use it in the `for` loop

---

In response to comment:

Before each iteration of the loop the test `elt.ELEMENT_NODE == elt.getNodeType()` is performed. This tests that the node referenced by `elt` is an element node (i.e. not a text node, attribute node, comment node etc). If the test fails then the body of the loop is executed.

In the body of the loop, `getElementIdx` is called to calcuate the relative position of this node amongst any siblings of the same name. This value is stored in `idx` but nothing is done with it and the value is then discarded.

After the body of the loop is executed, the update `elt = (DOMElement) elt.getParentNode()` is performed. This changes `elt` to reference the parent node of the node it previously referenced.

As a first step, I would change `elt.ELEMENT_NODE == elt.getNodeType()` to `Node.DOCUMENT_NODE == elt.getNodeType()` *(see comment from Paŭlo Ebermann below)* as this will cause your program to work back through the parent nodes until it finds the root of the document

Comment: so does this mean that basically, on each iteration, elt = parent node ? so when there's no more parent node, it will stop?

Comment: I've added some detail to the answer to deal with your comment

Comment: For the `ELEMENT_NODE` (or `DOCUMENT_NODE`) constant, better use `Node.ELEMENT_NODE` instead of referring to it with some object - it's less confusing.

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann - Good point - I'll edit that in. The original code posted in the question has many other problems beyond that, unfortunately

Answer (score 3):

In javascript, the second part of the for statement `for (DOMElement sib = (DOMElement) elt.getPreviousSibling(); sib ; sib = (DOMElement) sib.getPreviousSibling())` (which is `; sib;`), will be checking if sib is defined. To convert this to Java, you need to do `; sib != null;`. That should be equivalent.

So the whole for statement becomes `for (DOMElement sib = (DOMElement) elt.getPreviousSibling(); sib != null ; sib = (DOMElement) sib.getPreviousSibling())`